# How can I swap opposite corners on the same face of a 2x2 cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I've been experimenting with using Y-permutations to solve the 2x2 cube as described [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Solving-a-2x2-Rubiks-Cube-Blindfolded/). I ended up with the cube solved but for a single face where the opposite corners were swapped and disoriented. I managed to solve the cube, but I wonder if there is a shorter algorithm to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Y-perms, then simply rotate a face containing *one* of the corners 90 degrees, to position them opposite each other. This is called a setup move. Doing so puts the two corners opposite each other, and a Y-perm will then swap the correct corners.

You can then undo that setup move after completing the Y-perm by rotating the face back in place.

Answer (score 4):

Let the corners you want to swap be on the top left and bottom right of the top layer like [image: this]

Execute the algorithm: `R U' R' U' F2 U' R U R' D R2` where green is F and red is L