# Commutators in Rubik's cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, mechanical-puzzles

Can 4 corner be swapped at the same time with commutator in 3x3x3 Rubik's cube?

Generally, swapping any three and than swapping last one will help, but is it possible to do it in shorter ways using another supercomplex, one algortihmal commutator?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by swapping 4 corners. Maybe [the answer to this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/66023/20814) will help you to understand what is or isn't possible.

Comment: Is a 4-corner swap any movement of four corners? e.g. swap 2 corners and swap 2 corners (does it matter if it is a "horizontal" swap or a "diagonal" swap? or a cycle of 4 corners only?

Comment: Call this E-perm algorithm A := x' L' U L D' L' U' L D L' U' L D' L' U L D x. Then [A, L2] is a commutator that swaps four corners (2c2c) on the left face. Is this what you meant?